# Usage of AggregationContainer in ElasticSearch NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, aggregation, nest

I have yet to find a documentation on this part. Is there a correct way to build an AggregationContainer similar to how we would build a QueryContainer? A very rough example:

```
.Aggregations(a =>
    {
          AggregationContainer aggr = null;
          if (variableA) //if value of variableA is true
              aggr &= //concatenate aggregation statement here, e.g fieldA == variableA
          return aggr;
     }
)
```

Or is there any other way that I could incorporate if else statement, ranges in aggregation?

It would be lovely to include a few more possible examples of how AggregationContainer can be used. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The NEST documentation has been updated in the code repository around aggregations and we will update the public documentation site soon. We will be sure to visit this use case in the documentation. I've created a ticket for documenting this here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/838 and will answer as soon as we've done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AggregationDescriptor to append

```
var qryRes11 = client.Search<object>(x => x
.Aggregations(a =>
{
    AggregationDescriptor<object> v = new AggregationDescriptor<object>();
    v.Terms("a", tr =>
    {
        TermsAggregationDescriptor<object> trmAggDescriptor = new TermsAggregationDescriptor<object>();
        trmAggDescriptor.Field("a");
        trmAggDescriptor.Size(0);
        return trmAggDescriptor;
    });
    return v;
}));
var terms1 = qryRes1.Aggs.Terms("a");
```